# Jquery получить содержимое в 2 переменных

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

Подскажите как можно в jquery получить ответ в 2 или нескольких частях после запроса post?
Например есть такой код:

```
var path_script = "test.php";
    $.post(path_script, {p10: v_cost10, p13: v_cost13}, function(data){
        if (data.length > 0){
            console.log(data);
            $(".container").html(data);
            //$(".container2").html(data);
        };
    });
```

В файле test.php формируются данные, большой html блок текста. И полученное содержимое я вставляю в тег container.

А как сделать чтобы в тег container2 я мог вставить другой блок html? Т.е. как можно получить два разных содержимых? Как это оформить в php файле и js?

**[UPD] Решено**

В файле test.php разбил нужные части с помощью `<div id="firstpart">` и `<div id="secondpart">`

А в файле js отфильтровал в 2 переменные и сделал вывод как я хотел:

```
var str1 = $(data).filter('#firstpart').html();
var str2 = $(data).filter('#secondpart').html();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

верните json, или просто сделайте

```
var $data=$(data);
$('.container').html($data.find('#firstpart').children());
$('.container1').html($data.find('#secondpart').children());
```

в ответе возвращайте два блока с id='firstpart' и 'secondpart'

Comment: console.log($data.find('#firstpart').children()); - отображает Object[]

Comment: попробовал, пока не выходит

Comment: php должно вернуть что-то типа:

    <div id='firstpart'><div>Hello</div></div>
    <div id='secondpart'><div>Hello2</div></div>

а, если без контейнера, то не find, а filter

ну или `$data=$('<div>').html(data)`

Comment: Получилось вот так:
var str1 = $(data).filter('#firstpart').html();
var str2 = $(data).filter('#secondpart').html();

Comment: @eicto большое спасибо за ответ!